# Why is loading chunks of data into the cpu cache an efficient way of processing?

Tags: cpu-cache

I know that loading instructions into the cache increases the speed of processing overall. Is the answer to the question connected to organization and speed?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more what you're after? Because this looks like a programming question, and if so, you need to be on a network site.

Comment: I'm not looking at the ins and outs of cache management. I want to know the answer to the main above question in VERY general terms

Comment: @user3324945 - The above question is not clear.  I would also say its actually very inefficient to process chunks of data.  Your actual question isn't all that clear.

Comment: My answer to ["Why would computers transfer data and instructions from main memory to cache in blocks when this means a single cache miss may overwrite a lot"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22446371) (a closed question) may sufficiently answer your question.

Answer (score -1):

First, the "chunks" part of your question ...

Normally, memory management happens with chucks of memory. It doesn't make sense to manage memory byte by byte. That's because to manage a chunk of memory you need a data structure that contains info on that chunk of memory. Let's take a wild guess and say that that data structure is 24 bytes long. You wouldn't use a 24 byte data structure to manage 1 byte of memory. You want "economy of scale." Otherwise you get a horribly large amount of overhead. Instead you manage 1 Kbyte / 32 KBytes / 1 MByte / whatever at a time.

So, when memory is moved around (for example to the paging file) it's done in chunks and this same method applies to the cache.

To quote Wikipedia: "Data is transferred between memory and cache in blocks of fixed size, called cache lines. When a cache line is copied from memory into the cache, a cache entry is created."

The cache entry is an example of the data structure I mentioned before.

Remember that as program instructions are coming into the cache they are brought in in the same way as data is brought in. So the words "data is transferred" above also means "instructions are transferred."

Check out the Wikipedia entry below. It has more info.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache

======

And now a more general answer about the CPU cache.

Mainly, the speedup happens because when the CPU accesses the cache it gets the instructions/data MUCH! quicker than when it accesses main memory.

Here's an example. You have coded a loop in a program. On the first run through that section of memory will be brought into the cache. You start at the beginning of the loop and eventually get to the bottom of the loop. Then it's back to the top. Assuming that the whole loop fits in the cache (normal condition) the second time around those instructions are already in the cache and no more instruction fetches are needed for that loop. That really speeds things up. After the loop terminates it will eventually get overwritten in the cache by some other section of the program that needs to execute.

The same sort of thing applies to data. If some structure / group of variables / etc. is frequently being referenced or updated it will stay resident in the cache for some period of time. Eventually its space in the data cache will be given over to some other structure / group of variables / etc. because that is what the program begins to access frequently.